# rails editing rtf documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rtf

I want to edit (for example, replace any placeholder by any text) a **rtf** documents in **Rails application**.

What is the simplest way to provide it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options based on these [SO Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197708/what-are-the-best-options-for-rich-text-editing-in-rails) [--this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541693/rich-text-formatting-rtf-editor-plugins-for-rails-3-and-jquery-website).

[TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/)

[Rich Text Editor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/)

[CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor_for_jQuery)

[MarkItUp](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/)

[WMD](http://wmd-editor.com/)

However those are all from the UI.

If you want to manipulate it behind the scenes:

[Updated branch of ruby-rtf](https://github.com/thechrisoshow/rtf)

[Ruby-rtf](http://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-rtf)